# Trouble templating routes with > 1 slashes using Angular-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-routing

I'm having trouble on my **Express+Jade+AngularJS[v1.2.22]** application when I try to get routes like `"mydomain.com/something/somethingelse"` or `"mydomain.com/something/another/last"`...etc. (with one or more path subdivisions).

What happens is that the Angular route provider somehow cannot find what to template on this cases and doesn't render anything beneath the `<div ng-view>` tag, while entering a loop that causes the page to freeze and display a `"WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once"` console log over and over.

**Here's my angular module route configuration in `app.js`:**

```
var advocat = angular.module('advocat', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/index.html',
      controller: 'IndexCtrl',
      title: 'Inici'
    }).
    when('/eines/mapa', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/index.html',
      title: 'AB'
    }). 
    otherwise({
      templateUrl: 'partials/404.html',
      title: "Pàgina no trobada"
    });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

As far as I've been able to debug, I've found that the problem does only happen when the route that is requested has a `templateUrl` which hasn't been used previously since the page load. I'll try to explain that using my app.js routing configuration as an example:

**1st:** Page load, `"/whatever"` gets requested -> Page loads with template `'partials/404.html'` as the route doesn't match any `.when` angular uses `.otherwise` (no error happens because the route does not have subdivisions).

**2nd:** `"/eines/mapa"` gets requested using a link in the page **->** Error (It should template with `'partials/index.html'` template and it hadn't been used before).

Suppose that in **2nd** `"/whatever/whatever2"` had been requested instead of `"/eines/mapa"` **->** No error because it templates with `'partials/404.html'` (`.otherwise`) and this template had already been used in **1st** page load (would have also worked in a case where the `'partials/404.html'` template had been used a couple requests before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was caused by the `templateUrl` path, it should be `'/partials/index.html'` and not `'partials/index.html'`.

Otherwise, when angular makes an HTTP GET request to the server to get the template HTML file, it requests for the relative path. If the route specified is something like `'/example/example2'` angular will request the `templateUrl` in the path `'/example/partials/index.html'`, causing an error.